# Loki retention period s3 + dynamo

Tags: kubernetes, grafana-loki

I have a question about the retention mechanism in grafana-loki
I need store logs for one year and be able to query them
Setup is in k8s with the official Loki chart

below is my config

```
  auth_enabled: false
  ingester:
    chunk_idle_period: 5m
    chunk_block_size: 262144
    chunk_retain_period: 1m
    # max_transfer_retries: 0
    lifecycler:
      ring:
        kvstore:
          store: inmemory
        replication_factor: 1
  limits_config:
    enforce_metric_name: false
    reject_old_samples: true
    reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h
  schema_config:
    configs:
      - from: 2020-05-15
        store: aws
        object_store: s3
        schema: v11
        index:
          prefix: loki_index_prod_
          period: 8760h
          tags:
            env: prod-loki
  server:
    http_listen_port: 3100
  storage_config:
    aws:
      s3: s3://us-east-1/loki-prod-t
      s3forcepathstyle: true
      dynamodb:
        dynamodb_url: dynamodb://us-east-1
  table_manager:
    index_tables_provisioning:
      inactive_read_throughput: 5
      inactive_write_throughput: 5
      provisioned_write_throughput: 10
      provisioned_read_throughput: 10
    chunk_tables_provisioning:
      inactive_read_throughput: 5
      inactive_write_throughput: 5
      provisioned_write_throughput: 10
      provisioned_read_throughput: 10
    retention_deletes_enabled: true
    retention_period: 8760h
    creation_grace_period: 24h
```

Now retention is configured for a year, but when the retention period is exited new table in dynamodb will be created, and the old one will be immediately deleted?

In this case, I will lose all logs from the previous year and start from scratch?

Another aspect is how to deal with the retention of chunks in s3?

Please advice ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll not lose all logs from the previous year and start from scratch. The Table Manager keeps the last tables alive using the following formula:

```
number_of_tables_to_keep = floor(retention_period / table_period) + 1
```

In your case:

number_of_tables_to_keep = 8760 / 8760 + 1 = 2

See the Loki documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/table-manager/).

Comment: What with s3 chunks?

Comment: They're Loki chunks (https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/) created at the Amazon S3 service (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3).

Comment: yes i know what is chunk and what they do in Loki , but no any documentation about retention of chunks

Comment: Sorry, I read "what is" instead of "what with". I think it works the same way, but I'm not sure.